# Should a service with heavy initialization keep itself running?

Tags: android, performance, service

I have a `Service` which can be accessed via `Binder`. That `Service` requires a lot of work to initialize. Clients might rebind shortly after the unbound.

So naturally I would like to avoid the `Service` being stopped and restarted all the time.

Is it bad practice to keep a `Service` alive even if it currently does nothing? Does it have a performance impact on the device at all?

Relevant code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    startService(new Intent(this, this.getClass()));
    return new LocalBinder();
}
```

Comment: I don’t know about performance, but would hate that as a user.

Comment: @mvai as far as I understand it, Android will kill the service as soon as it needs the resources, and the service won't be restarted. Also a process without a running task should not impact the idle state. (However I am not sure about this; it is part of the question.)

Comment: Yes, Android will kill it if needed. As a developer, keeping it alive seems reasonable (it depends on your app really); as a user who bothers sometimes to look at running processes, I don’t like seeing them hanging around, especially if the app is not important for me, and is not supposed to do anything at that time. Also I seem to remember that only recently Android had some major memory management improvements, so this *might* be a big issue for older/cheaper devices, with old platform and cheap batteries.

Comment: Maybe, but also maybe not. That is why I ask here before I send code like this into production. Thanks for your user insight anyways. (Because I myself hate only those services which restart immediately after I killed them, it is good to know that others think different about this.)

Comment: Sure, let's wait for someone with a deeper knowledge of the matter :) mine was not an answer.